# Python script displaying menu twice before prompt

Tags: python

I am a beginner to Python and having difficulties with a short quiz I am creating.

I have created a short video, to show exactly what is happening: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHRAr0T-i-Q&feature=youtu.be

How can I have it so it comes up with the question, "Who is Conor Mcgregor?" and then print the answers and how can I stop it from repeating the question again underneath the answers?

My Code:

```
while True:
    question = input("Who is Conor Mcgregor?")
    print("A) A Chef")
    print("B) A Fighter")
    print("C) A Doctor")
    if len(question):
        answer = question
        if answer == "B" or answer == "b":
            print("Well Done! Conor Mcgregor is an MMA Fighter.")
            break
        elif answer == "A" or answer == "C":
            print("Wrong Answer!")
            break
        else:
            print("Error")
```

When run, this behaves as follows:

```
C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/msi/PycharmProjects/Reboot/Quiz.py
Who is Conor Mcgregor?
A) A Chef
B) A Fighter
C) A Doctor
Who is Conor Mcgregor?
```

How can I make it so it gives the question and then follows up with the answers? I am having to press a button before it proceeds with the answers, and then when the answers show, the question is there again.

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: Instead of creating a video, include the relevant code in your question.  The code isn't really readable in that video.

Comment: Sufficient information to answer a question needs to be **included in the question itself** to be compliant with site rules. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122 describing why we don't accept images of code -- every one of those rationales (inability to search, folks who can't view content from work, lack of screen reader support) applies to videos as well.

Comment: Also note the documentation on building a [mcve] -- the **shortest possible code** that reproduces a given problem.

Comment: Much better! Still missing is the error or exception.

Comment: (BTW, which version of Python is this? Behavior of `input()` is very different between Python 2 and Python 3).

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6

Comment: Could you [edit] to include a transcript (copied-and-pasted from the terminal) of the behavior you're asking about? That would show us (among other things) how you're actually invoking the program.

Comment: Hopefully that is better

Comment: Much better! Unfortunately, I'm not able to reproduce that bug myself -- works fine (only prompts once) using the exact code given in the question with Python on a Mac.

Comment: Oh, wait. Do you mean you want to see the menu before the prompt? **Print it first**, then -- that is to say, actually put the `print()`s for the menu above the `input()` for the prompt.

Comment: Basically, I'd like the program to ask the question and follow up with the answers right after, but I'm having to press a button to show the answers

Comment: And then, when I show the answers, it says the "Who is Conor Mcgregor" again, for some reason.

Comment: Yeah. `input()` waits for the user to respond, so the `print()`s don't happen until after the user responded when you call `input()` first.

Comment: Why don't you make the first line just `print("Who is Connor MacGregor?")` and then `answer = input("Your answer:")` later?

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll try that. Is there a reason it ends up saying the question again too? Or, is that because of the input?

Comment: That's how it's written: When you just press enter, `len(question)` is zero, which is falsey in Python, so it goes back to the top of the loop (and, at the top of the loop, it prints everything again)

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot - Really appreciate it! :D

Comment: BTW, no need to edit "fixed" into your question -- clicking the checkbox on an answer, as you already have, flags it as resolved. And editing a question *into a different question* after you've already gotten answers is very much frowned on, as it makes those answers no longer make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to print the question then ask for input:

```
print("Who is Conor Mcgregor?")
print("A) A Chef")
print("B) A Fighter")
print("C) A Doctor")
answer = input('A/B/C?: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with a loop

```
while True:
    print("Who is Conor Mcgregor? ")
    print("A) A Chef")
    print("B) A Fighter")

    answer = raw_input()
    if answer == "B":
        print("Correct!")
        break
    elif answer == "A":
        print("Wrong! The correct answer was B! Conor Mcgregor is a Fighter.")
        break
    print("Please enter a valid answer!")
```

Or with a function

```
def question():
    print("Who is Conor Mcgregor? ")
    print("A) A Chef")
    print("B) A Fighter")

    answer = raw_input()
    if answer == "B":
        print "Correct!"
        return True
    elif answer == "A":
        print "Wrong! The correct answer was B! Conor Mcgregor is a Fighter."
        return True
    print("Please enter a valid answer!")
    question()
question()
```

you also need to change the input for raw_input if you work with python 2.7